# Excel VBA Function to determine row number

Tags: excel, vba, function, range

I built a function to determine the first row in which data exists.  When I call the data i keep getting an error stating object required.  How do I get around this error and is this the best way to accomplish my goal?  TYIA!

```
Sub rename()

Dim strOldType As String
Dim correctrow As Long
Dim a As Range

Set a = startrow(correctrow)

Range("s" & a).Select
strOldType = Selection.Value
End Sub
```

```
Function startrow(firstroww)
Dim strRow As String
Dim firstrow As Range

Range("ab1").Select
strRow = Selection.Value

If strRow <> "" Then
firstroww = 1
Else
Range("ab1").Activate
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
firstroww = ActiveCell.Row()
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome. Please show the actual error message and line of code causing it. Have you read [VBA identify first and last rows with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179096/) or any other posts that deal with finding the first row with content. You are expected to do your own research, and if these other posts don't apply to your situation, then at least "...keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA identify first and last rows with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179096/vba-identify-first-and-last-rows-with-data)

Comment: You have not assigned a value to `correctrow`, but you use it to set a range. Then you use a range in a string for a cell address. What??? You need to get clear about what data types you are using in what context.

Comment: use WorksheetFunction.CountA(), as demonstrated below:

`Dim row As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet

For i = 1 To sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Set row = sheet.Rows(i)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(row) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "row " & i & " is empty"
    End If

Next i` You can adopt it to set the Range or to set the Function return value. Avoid to use `Select`.

Comment: @skkakkar why not add that as a solution instead of a comment? Then you can actually read it

Comment: @urdearboy I am not sure whether OP wants function or Sub. His approach seems confusing . He starts with Sub ands with End Function. Further code suggested by me is appropriate for Sub but for making function it may have to tweaked for which i may not be able to proceeed further presently.

Comment: If you look closer, there is indeed a full sub and a function. I will edit his question and separate them accordingly so it is clear @skkakkar

Comment: Tedinoz and skkakkar thanks for the input!  It allowed me to get in the right direction.  teylyn this is my first time using vba and i have no formal training.  im sure im committing some sort of blasphemy so i apologize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a function like this. You will need to pass a range into the function as seen below in `Sub Test()`.

The custom function can find the first used cell below from any starting point.

```
Option Explicit

Function FR(Start As Range) As Long

Select Case Start
    Case <> ""
        FR = Start.Row
    Case Else
        FR = Start.End(xlDown).Row
End Select

End Function
```

```
Sub Test()

MsgBox FR(Range("A1"))

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the simple example.  The trouble that I am having is in case the first record happens to be on the first row.

Comment: I couldnt get it to work but when I changed your first case statement from Case "*" to Case is <> "" it worked!  Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- Don't try to use Select inside a function.
- Use `Set` to assign a range object. **Do not** use `Set` to assign a number to a variable.
- Make up your mind whether you want a row number or a range object. You bounce back and forth between the two with no regard for result.

Corrected code:

```
Sub rename()

    Dim strOldType As String
    Dim correctrow As Long
    Dim a As LONG     '<~~ correction

    correctrow = 1     '<~~ correction
    a = startrow(correctrow)     '<~~ correction

    strOldType = Range("s" & a).Value

End Sub

Function startrow(firstroww)

    if Range("ab" & firstrow) <> "" then     '<~~ correction
        startrow = firstrow
    else
        startrow = Range("ab" & firstrow).end(xldown).row
    end if

End Function
```

Comment: I dim firstrow as long to the function but then kept getting "Method Range of object '_Gobal failed" error.  I appreciate trying to help me understand what i did wrong with my existing code.  That helps me learn

Answer (score 0):

## First Cell in Column Function

It is assumed that you're looking for a VBA function to use in Excel to calculate the first non-empty row of a column (specified by a range).

### Features

- The `Volatile` method marks a user-defined function as volatile. A
  volatile function must be recalculated whenever calculation occurs in
  any cells on the worksheet. A nonvolatile function is recalculated
  only when the input variables change (VBA Help).
- At least for the sake of correctness, you have to use `IsEmpty`
  instead of "" for the reason e.g. if the cell in the resulting row
  contains a formula that evaluates to "", it will be ignored.
- The Find Method Version uses the Find method to calculate the First Row, which is safer than
  the End Version e.g. if you input a value into the first cell of the
  column i.e. the result is 1 and you hide the first row, the result of
  the End Version will not be 1.
- The formula can be inserted in the same column as `SelectRange`
  Column. In some cases the **End** Version would not show the correct
  result or create a circular reference. Therefore `ThisCell` is used
  in the **End** version and 0 is returned if no value was found in `SelectRange` column.

### Find Method Version

```
Function FirstRowFind(SelectRange As Range) As Long

    Application.Volatile

    Dim FirstCell As Range

    With Columns(SelectRange.Column)
        Set FirstCell = .Find("*", .Cells(.Cells.Count), -4123, 1, 2, 1)
    End With

    If Not FirstCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstRowFind = FirstCell.Row
    End If

End Function
```

**Find Method**

Instead of

```
Set FirstCell = .Find("*", .Cells(.Cells.Count), -4123, 1, 2, 1)
```

you can use

```
Set FirstCell = .Find("*", .Cells(.Cells.Count), _
        xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext)
```

or

```
Set FirstCell = .Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
```

The parameters for the arguments `LookAt`(unimportant in this case) and `SearchDirection`(Default is `Next`) can be omitted, but since I couldn't find any difference in efficiency, I didn't.

**Usage in Excel**

For Column `AB`:

```
=FirstRowFind(AB1)
=FirstRowFind(AB20)
=FirstRowFind(AB17:AH234)
```

### End Version (Not recommended)

```
Function FirstRowEnd(SelectRange As Range) As Long

    Application.Volatile

    Dim FirstCell As Range

    If Application.ThisCell.Column = SelectRange.Column Then Exit Function

    If Not IsEmpty(SelectRange.Cells(1)) Then
        FirstRowEnd = 1
      Else
        Set FirstCell = Cells(1, SelectRange.Column).End(xlDown)
        FirstRowEnd = FirstCell.Row
        If FirstRowEnd = Rows.Count And IsEmpty(FirstCell) Then
            FirstRowEnd = 0
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

**Usage in Excel**

For Column `AB`:

```
=FirstRowEnd(AB1)
=FirstRowEnd(AB20)
=FirstRowEnd(AB17:AH234)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column
```

The UsedRange object is the largest rectangle covering all nonempty cells.

Comment: This doesn't work as i usually have some sort of header not relevant to my dataset a couple of rows above the dataset.

Comment: Well that case only the End method is useful. If your data structure is consistent, things would be a lot easier.